# Does IE8 seem to strip the hash off any form actions containing them?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

It seems like you can't link to a URI which contains a hash, at least using the Spoon IE8  executable, since it strips them after submission.

Would be great if someone can report using a legit IE8 whether it appends the hash or not.

**Note**: Just realized the Spoon version that I have is Release Candidate 1, so it's definitely not the real thing.

[Demo](http://static.arounds.org/form.html)

Comment: I can totally agree! IE8 kills my hash-relating app as it simply cuts off everything from the hash sign.

Answer (score 1):

send your hash in a parameter so that way ie wont remove it 
if you have :
www.domain.com/page#hashdestination
use:
 www.domain.com/page?hash=#hashdestination
this trick  works in all major  browsers

Comment: Looks interesting, but this will definitly lead to a lot of problems when reading the GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think for this is to just submit to a proxy page which does a header redirect with the hash.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, hashes are completely ignored in URLs for requests. The way I understand it, browsers strip off the hash part, then submit the request, then attempt to scroll to an element matching that hash id.

What do you need to submit a hash for anyway?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, IE9/IE7 successfully preserve the hash. The point of the hash is to indicate the step, because I'm linking to a specific step in an ajax app.